# AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'new' occurs when trying to use Pytorchs AlexNet Lighting preprocessing

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to train my model on `ImageNet` using `inception` and `Alexnet` like preprocessing. I used [Fast-ai imagenet training script](https://github.com/fastai/imagenet-fast/blob/master/imagenet_nv/fastai_imagenet.py) provided script.   `Pytorch` has support for `inception` like preprocessing but for `AlexNet`s `Lighting`, we have to implement it ourselves :

```
__imagenet_pca = {
    'eigval': torch.Tensor([0.2175, 0.0188, 0.0045]),
    'eigvec': torch.Tensor([
        [-0.5675,  0.7192,  0.4009],
        [-0.5808, -0.0045, -0.8140],
        [-0.5836, -0.6948,  0.4203],
    ])
}

# Lighting data augmentation taken from here - https://github.com/eladhoffer/convNet.pytorch/blob/master/preprocess.py
class Lighting(object):
    """Lighting noise(AlexNet - style PCA - based noise)"""

    def __init__(self, alphastd, eigval, eigvec):
        self.alphastd = alphastd
        self.eigval = eigval
        self.eigvec = eigvec

    def __call__(self, img):
        if self.alphastd == 0:
            return img

        alpha = img.new().resize_(3).normal_(0, self.alphastd)
        rgb = self.eigvec.type_as(img).clone()\
            .mul(alpha.view(1, 3).expand(3, 3))\
            .mul(self.eigval.view(1, 3).expand(3, 3))\
            .sum(1).squeeze()
        return img.add(rgb.view(3, 1, 1).expand_as(img))
```

which is finally used like this :

```
train_tfms = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(size),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ColorJitter(.4,.4,.4),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        Lighting(0.1, __imagenet_pca['eigval'], __imagenet_pca['eigvec']),
        normalize,
    ])
    train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(traindir, train_tfms)
    train_sampler = (torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(train_dataset)
                     if args.distributed else None)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=(train_sampler is None),
        num_workers=args.workers, pin_memory=True, sampler=train_sampler)
```

However, the problem is, whenever I run the script I get the:

> 'AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'new''

Which complains about this line:

`alpha = img.new().resize_(3).normal_(0, self.alphastd)`

I am clueless as to why this is happening. I'm using Pytorch 0.4 by the way.

Comment: It looks like you're receiving a PIL Image in your function instead of a Pytorch tensor. I've run your code and it works, can you check that ToTensor() is being executed?

Comment: @iacolippo: Thanks alot, you comment actually made me spot my error! I had used the ToTensor() after the lighting() and that has made this issue ! swapting their place solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @iacolippo's comment, I finally found the cause!

Unlike the example I wrote here, in my actual script, I had used `transforms.ToTensor()` after the `lighting()` method. Doing so resulted in a `PIL` image being sent as the input for `lightining()`which expects a Tensor and that's why the error occurs.

So basically the snippet I posted in the question is correct and `.ToTensor` has to be used prior to calling `Lighting()`.